# Pulling from google container registry in Jenkins scripted pipeline on compute engine vm

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I've setup Jenkins on a Google Cloud compute engine vm. Docker is installed, and I'm successfully using a scripted pipeline to pull and run public docker images. I can't seem to pull from Google Container registry though, and I can't find any examples of how to do this in a scripted pipeline. Here's my Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
    checkout scm
    docker.image('mysql:5.7').withRun('--env MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306') { c ->
        docker.image('mysql:5.7').inside("--link ${c.id}:db") {
            /* Wait until mysql service is up */
            sh 'while ! mysqladmin ping -hdb --silent; do sleep 1; done'
        }
        /* Fails here */
        docker.image('gcr.io/my-project/my-image').withRun("--link ${c.id}:db --env MYSQL_HOST=localhost --env MYSQL_USER=root --env MYSQL_PWD=password --env MYSQL_DB=my_db --network=host")
    }
}
```

It seems like since I'm on a compute engine vm, there shouldn't need to be any credential configuration for Jenkins (clearly I'm wrong). I've run `gcloud auth configure-docker` on the vm, and I can easily ssh in and pull the image I want from gcr.io with a simple `docker pull`. When jenkins tries to pull though, I get `Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication`.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I've discovered wrapping my pull step with `docker.withRegistry()` works, but this requires me to add my gcloud credentials via the Jenkins interface. It seems strange that I need to do this since Jenkins is already running on a compute engine vm that has the correct auth and docker correctly configured to be able to pull from gcr.io. Is there some special way Jenkins (or the docker pipeline plugin) is running docker that it somehow doesn't have the same authentication that docker has when run manually on the vm?

Comment: Authentication fixed the issue for me. We had a similar issue with CircleCI and GCR authentication. We fixed it with: 
```
      - image: gcr.io/gcpug-container/appengine-go:1.11-slim
        auth:
          username: _json_key
          password: ${GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY}
```

Comment: Yeah I've actually done this in a couple ways with circleci, that one included. Its not quite a straightforward with the Jenkins scripted pipeline, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Cracked this, and it was a bit silly. While I did indeed setup auth correctly for *my* user on the vm, I did not do this for the *jenkins* user on the vm. After ssh-ing into the vm, I needed to do:

```sh
sudo su jenkins
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

This adds the gcloud config for docker to jenkins' home directory. Then you have no need for `withRegistry` or any additional jenkins credential configuration. Nice and clean if you are doing this on a vm.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you’re running into some auth issues with Jenkins & Docker on a GCE VM.

This document may help [1], and also, did you have the chance of looking into a helper [2]?

---

[1] https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#using-google-compute-engine

[2] https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#helpers

Comment: I've already used `gcloud auth configure-docker` to add the credential helper to docker. I can easily pull an image myself with `docker pull gcr.io/...`, but for some reason Jenkins can't do this exact same thing. It seems its somehow unable to use the auth setup already on the vm.